# How can I check for color of single a pixel in CGContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I want to check for a color in a single pixel in a CGContext. I have tried using this guide here http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/. However i've tried it with no success. I don't want to get a context from a image because   I already got a context that is not visible on screen. Is it possible to find single pixel color in a CGContext and if it's possible how can i do that?. Google have gave me no answer. Down below you can se how I have declared my context.

```
- (BOOL) initContext:(CGSize)size {

    float scaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

     // scaleFactor = 1; non-retina
    // scalefactor = 2; retina

    int bitmapByteCount;
    int bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow = (size.width * 4);
    bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height)*scaleFactor*scaleFactor;

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    cacheBitmap = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (cacheBitmap == NULL){
        return NO;
    }

    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    cacheContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (cacheBitmap, size.width*scaleFactor, size.height *scaleFactor, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow*scaleFactor, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);

       CGContextScaleCTM(cacheContext, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
       CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

  CGContextSetRGBFillColor(cacheContext, 0, 0, 0, 0.0);
   CGContextFillRect(cacheContext, (CGRect){CGPointZero, CGSizeMake(size.height*scaleFactor, size.width*scaleFactor)});

    return YES;
}
```

Basically I want a method where i can input a point and get the color from cacheContext.

Answer (score 0):

If `cacheBitmap` is the pointer to your pixels, then a pixel at (x,y) can be found using the following:

```
uint8_t* pixel = (uint8_t*)cacheBitmap + (y * bitmapRowBytes) + (x * 4);
uint8_t  alpha = pixel [ 0 ];
uint8_t  red = pixel [ 1 ];
uint8_t  green = pixel [ 2 ];
uint8_t  blue = pixel [ 3 ];
```

However, your `bitmapBytesPerRow` is calculated incorrectly. If you're allocating a bitmap that is `width * scaleFactor` by `height * scaleFactor`, then your `bitmapRowBytes` needs to account for that. It should be:

```
bitmapRowBytes = size.width * 4 * scaleFactor;
```

Comment: Thank you, but how am I supposed to do addition with void*? I get the error message invalid operand to binary

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a cast. Adding it now.

Comment: are you sure that alpha is pixel[3] and not pixel[0]? The bitmap info is: kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst.

Comment: If that's how you specified it, then that's how it is. I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: I changed       `bitmapBytesPerRow = (size.width * 4*scaleFactor);
 bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height)*scaleFactor*scaleFactor; and     uint8_t* pixel = (uint8_t*)cacheBitmap + ((uint8_t)point.y * bitmapBytesPerRow) + ((uint8_t)point.x * 4);
    uint8_t  red = pixel [ 1 ];
    uint8_t  green = pixel [ 2 ];
    uint8_t  blue = pixel [ 3 ];
    uint8_t  alpha = pixel [ 0 ];`. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Could I ask you per mail a few questions?

Comment: I'm not comfortable giving out my email at this time. However, I just noticed that the `bitmapRowBytes` you're passing to `CGBitmapContextCreate()` is being multiplied by `scaleFactor`. You no longer need to do that since you've fixed `bitmapRowBytes`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51939/discussion-between-freddy-and-user1118321)

Comment: Oops! Sorry I missed this. I had to step out.